# Angular2 datepicker input data-binding

Tags: javascript, angular, data-binding, datepicker

I have `angular2` app where I have used `datepicker`.In which I am binding value initially from `json`(01.01.9999 01:00) and some other setting.

It works fine but there one button which sets specific date (01.01.2099 00:00).
It works fine as well but in `datepicker` input value is getting unchanged.
How can I fix this problem.

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">End Date :</label>
    <div class="col-md-6" style="bottom: 22px">
        {{break.EndDate | amDateFormat:'DD.MM.YYYY HH:mm'}}
        <date-time-datepicker [Id]="'endDate'" (dateSelected)="endDate = $event" initValue="{{break.EndDate | amDateFormat:'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm'}}" viewformat="DD.MM.YYYY HH:mm" postformat="YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm" caption=""></date-time-datepicker>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" (click)="setMaxBreakEndDate()">MAX</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image]

```
setMaxSelectedBreakValidTo() {
      this.break.EndDate = moment(new Date(2099, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0)).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm');
    }
```

Comment: `this.break = this.break;` why this ? Don't you think this will bind same value everytime?

Comment: sorry i forgot remove this old line